# Insert Rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I have a master excel workbook that employees use for data entry. Each of them downloads a copy to their desktops and then marks their progress on various entries by entering an "x" in a comlun next to the data they've finished. Each product has its own row with its respective data listed across that row. The master workbook is filled out throughout the quarter with new data for the products as it becomes available, which is currently updated on each individuals workbook by use of a macro that simply copies the range where the data is (see code below).

```
Sub GetDataFromClosedWorkbook()
'Created by XXXX 5/2/2014
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' turn off the screen updating

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("LOCATION OF FILE", True, True)
' open the source workbook, read only
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
' read data from the source workbook: (Left of (=) is paste @ destination, right of it is copy)
.Range("F8:K25").Value = wb.Worksheets("1").Range("F8:K25").Value
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
' read data from the source workbook: (Left of (=) is paste @ destination, right of it is copy)
.Range("V5:Z359").Value = wb.Worksheets("2").Range("V5:Z359").Value
End With

wb.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving any changes
Set wb = Nothing ' free memory
Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' turn on the screen updating

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is this: every once and a while, I'll need to add a new product, which adds a row on the master (this is opposed to adding data, which is just added across the row). Sometimes this row is at the end, sometimes it's in the middle. As you can see from the code below, my VBA currently can't handle this row change as it is just copy/pasting from a predefined range. Each users's workbook does not pick up on this change in row # and thus the data in the colums becomes associated with the wrong rows. Normally, you could just copy the entire sheet and problem solved. The issue I have is that each user needs to be able to record their own process in their own workbook next to their data. Is there a way to code this so that a new row on the master sheet will be accounted for and added to all the others without erasing/moving the marks made by each user? I've been trying to find a way to make it "insert" rows if they're new in the master, as this would preserve the data, but can't figure it out. Also, due to security on the server at work- linking workbooks, etc is not an option. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Does each product have a unique name or some other unique identifier?

Comment: Yes, they do. The first 7 or so columns are all unique to the product and could each be an identifier on their own.

Comment: When you're updating the master workbook, are you only adding new products, or do you ever update an existing row?

Comment: I update existing rows and I add them, too. So imagine you have the product name, serial # and a few other identifiers in the leftmost columns--then after that I have performance, depreciation, etc which is updated for each product. Products (rows) are added intermittently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this problem would be using the `Scripting.Dictionary` Object. You could create a dictionary for both the target and source identifiers and compare those. I suppose you don't really need the Key-Value pair to achieve this, but hopefully this gets you on the right track!

```
Sub Main()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
Dim dictSource As Object
Dim dictTarget As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim idSource As String
Dim idTarget As String
Dim offset As Integer

Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

offset = 9 'My data starts at row 10, so the offset will be 9

Set rng = source.Range("A10:A" & source.Cells(source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set dictSource = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each cell In rng
    dictSource.Add Key:=cell.Value, Item:=cell.Row
Next

Set rng = target.Range("A10:A" & target.Cells(target.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set dictTarget = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each cell In rng
    dictTarget.Add Key:=cell.Value, Item:=cell.Row
Next

i = 1
j = source.Range("A10:A" & source.Cells(source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
Do While i <= j
Retry:
    idSource = source.Cells(i + offset, 1).Value
    idTarget = target.Cells(i + offset, 1).Value
    If Not (dictSource.Exists(idTarget)) And idTarget <> "" Then
        'Delete unwanted rows
        target.Cells(i + offset, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo Retry
    End If
    If dictTarget.Exists(idSource) Then
        'The identifier was found so we can update the values here...
        dictTarget.Remove (idSource)
    ElseIf idSource <> "" Then
        'The identifier wasn't found so we can insert a row
        target.Cells(i + offset, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        'And you're ready to copy the values over
        target.Cells(i + offset, 1).Value = idSource
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set dictSource = Nothing
Set dictTarget = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: One oversight that I noticed in the code above is that if the list of identifiers on the `target` sheet is longer than the one on the `source` sheet, the remaining rows won't be dealt with. I don't know if this is a situation that you will end up in - but it's good to note it.

Comment: This looks great, thank you! I'm going to play around with it a bit later when I have some time and will get back to you. Just looking at this quickly, this is creating the dictionary from one column in the master sheet, correct? What I'm thinking is this (again, I still have to play with it) If I run this code, it will add a row for that info, so then I should be able to modify my old code to update the new range on the target sheet afterwards, right? Thanks for your help on this- I'm looking forward to trying it out

Comment: It is creating a dictionary from one column both in the master sheet and the target sheet - `dictSource` has the column from the master sheet that has your identifiers and `dictTarget` contains the same identifiers in the target sheet. Rows will be inserted to try and match the target sheet with the master sheet without replacing data from identifiers present in both dictionaries. You could probably do this with a single dictionary, or even without one, as this is just using the `Exists` function to search keys.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, thanks! I'll get back to you after I've had some time to play with it later today and let you know how it goes. Would you say the `Exists` function would have any real advantage off the top of your head as opposed to the `dictSource` & `dictTarget`? I owe you some reasearch and trial/error on my end at this point- just wondering if you have an opinion

Comment: I'm glad that it's doing what you need - though I do feel the need to clear one thing up. The `Exists` function is a part of the `Scripting.Dictionary` object, so IT is the reason why I chose to use `dictSource` and `dictTarget` in the first place. The functionality we use the dictionaries for is to simply list the identifiers and search that list for possible matches - you could do this without the dictionaries by using lists or arrays and creating a function to search for a specific identifier. Check out [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) for detailed info.

Comment: Ok- I had to change the dict parts to:                              `For Each Cell In rng
    If Not dictTarget.exists(Cell.Value) Then
    dictTarget.Add Key:=Cell.Value, Item:=Cell.Row
    End If`                                                       But I've got it working now. The thing is, it deletes whatever is to the left of the column in the target sheet- can this be changed?

Comment: Nevermind- I was able to rewrite the end of your code to make it do exactly what I wanted! I deleted most of it and then just replaced it to make `idSource` <> `idTarget`. Thanks a million for your help on all of this- I never would have gotten it on my own.